# Is there any scope to increment digit in excel?

Tags: excel

I have created a UDF in excel. Here is the function with cell reference as arguments:

```
=getInfo($A$3,B2,3)
```

In the above arguments, "3" is actually the row number which will be used for a calculation. Now if I drag this UDF over rows, the B2 is incremented as it is a cell reference (Range) but 3 is not incremented as it is a digit only. I need to use this third argument sometimes fixed (which is actually works in current condition), but sometimes I need to increment this argument while dragging.

My query is, is there any scope/option to increment the only digit in UDF without passing an additional optional argument for increment (eg: 3+1 or let's say I put 3 in any cell and use that cell to increment it by 1 for every row dragging)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Row()` function. Try-

```
=getInfo($A$3,B2,Row(A3))
```

When you drag it to 1 cell down then formula will `=getInfo($A$3,B3,Row(A4))` means row argument 4.